Would Isaiah 61:1-3 qualify as the original gospel?
Isaiah 61:1-3 (KJV) in its entirety reads:

61:1 The spirit of the Lord GOD is upon me; because the LORD hath
anointed me to preach good tidings unto the meek; he hath sent me to
bind up the brokenhearted, to proclaim liberty to the captives, and the opening of the prison to them that are bound;
61:2 To proclaim the acceptable year of the LORD, and the day of
vengeance of our God; to comfort all that mourn;     61:3 To appoint
unto them that mourn in Zion, to give unto them beauty for ashes, the
oil of joy for mourning, the garment of praise for the spirit of
heaviness; that they might be called trees of righteousness, the
planting of the LORD, that he might be glorified.

Isaiah 61:1 uses the word tidings H1319 bâsar when transliterated and the characters which are בָּשַׂר; defined as “to bear news, bear tidings, publish, preach, show forth. In the Piel tense, it’s “to gladden with good news”.
Yahusha delivers Isaiah 61:1-2 almost verbatim to the listeners at the synagogue in Luke 4:17-21 (KJV)

4:17 And there was delivered unto him the book of the prophet Esaias.
And when he had opened the book, he found the place where it was
written,        4:18 The Spirit of the Lord is upon me, because he hath
anointed me to preach the gospel to the poor; he hath sent me to
heal the brokenhearted, to preach deliverance to the captives, and recovering of sight to the blind, to set at liberty them that are
bruised,        4:19 To preach the acceptable year of the Lord.
4:20 And he closed the book, and he gave it again to the minister, and
sat down. And the eyes of all them that were in the synagogue were
fastened on him.        4:21 And he began to say unto them, This day is
this scripture fulfilled in your ears.

When Yahusha delivered it at the synagogue, he was effectively saying that Yahuah is here to redeem the Israelites as He prophesied He would and to begin the reign of His Spirit indwelling the lives of believers here on earth.
Jesus himself also preached the gospel of the kingdom of God in Mark 1:14-15(KJV)

1:14 Now after that John was put in prison, Jesus came into Galilee,
preaching the gospel of the kingdom of God,     1:15 And saying, The
time is fulfilled (similar to Luke 4:21), and the kingdom of God is
at hand: repent ye, and believe the gospel.

The exercise of faith in the finished work of His Messiah is believing He actually did what He prophesied He would as evidenced by how the converted believer lives their life.
Conclusion: Through the death, burial and resurrection of Yahusha, Yahuah would redeem the Israelites from the curse of the law, which also enabled Yahuah to make good on His promise that believing Gentiles would also receive the blessing of Abraham (Galatians 3:13-14). That was the good news!!

I’m voting to close this question because this is a statement and not a question.

I’ve made an edit to what was my conclusion. Is there a specific part that is a statement?

You have answered your own question.  Therefore, It was not a genuine question to begin with.  If you wish to do this, simply ask the question and then enter an answer below.
